# Как присвоить функции F(1) значение 1 в самой функции?

Tags: python

Как присвоить функции F(1) значение 1 в самой функции?

```
def F(n):
    F(n-1) + n
print(F(30))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Стандартно - проверкой условия такие вещи делаются. И `return` ещё нужен, разумеется.
На всякий случай: ниже  применён тернарный оператор для лаконичности.

```
def F(n):
    return F(n-1) + n if n != 1 else 1
print(F(30))
```